# How can we derive that an accelerated charge particle will radiate EMWs?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

All the properties of the electromagnetic entity is said to be fully described by the four golden rules of Electromagnetism : The Maxwell's Equations.How can we derive that a charged particle will emit Electromagnetic Radiations when it will be accelerated?

Comment: I'd recommend the derivation by Professor Walter Lewin, MIT OCW Course 8.03. I'd write it out here, but it really requires the use of diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

In term of Maxwell's equations what you need to do is take the two curl equations, and then isolate and substitute:

$$
\nabla\times E +\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=0\\
\nabla\times B =\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
$$
So you take a time derivative of, say, the first, exchange nabla and differentiation by time (linear operators that are commutative) and then sub dE/dt into that.

Now you need some vector identities to connect terms of the sort $\nabla\times\nabla\times\vec{V}$ to simpler terms, and maybe use the remaining Maxwell equations.

** All this is done in vacuum - i.e. no currents.

You get a wave equation for B, as well as for E. the first temporal derivative of a field is due to the charge velocity. the second is due to the charge acceleration.

In terms of charge density $\rho$ you need to look up Jefemenko's equation.